# Antenna Ground/Attic

Tags: grounding, tv-antenna

I have mounted a Clearstream Antenna in my attic of a single story home, which is connected to my tv's via cable. Should I ground it and if so how? Can I run a Copper wire from the splitter to the ground in my electric  or is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 1):

If it's inside of the attic, it's not exposed to lightning or wind, which is why you ground them in the first place.

You don't need a ground here.

If your wire runs outside the house, however, it wouldn't be a bad idea to ground the wires.

Comment: I hope you mean ground the frame or the shield, grounding the “wires” would kill the signal.